# Apache Response timeout

Tags: apache, configuration, response, odoo-8, openerp-7

I have configure apache2 into my ubuntu 14.04 with odoo.DB has over 100000 records i for partners. So we are loading them into background. Same way products are also loading. Products are loading fine, but partner are not loading. Can any one help me with this.

```
apache proxy configuration.
```

`
    ServerName odoo-bhaviraj.com
    ServerAlias odoo-bhaviraj.com

```
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/odoo-bhaviraj.com.error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/odoo-bhaviraj.com.access.log combined

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyVia full
ProxyTimeout 18000
KeepAlive On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8069/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8069/

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8069/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8069/
</VirtualHost>

 odoo.conf file

[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = acespritech
db_password = 123456
addons_path = /home/bhaviraj/project/erp/odoo/odoo_8/addons
## Logging Group - Logging Configuration
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
logrotate = True
syslog = False
log_level = debug
log_handler = [':INFO']
log_level = info
db_filter = .*
workers = 4
proxy_mode = True
limit_memory_soft = 671088640


limit_memory_hard = 805306368
limit_time_cpu = 3000
limit_time_real = 3000
limit_request = 8192
max_cron_threads = 0
xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
longpolling_port = 8072`
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, execute this commande :

> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
> ```

And, verify the Timeout *(The number of seconds before receives and sends time)*.

> Timeout 300

Comment: i have extended the time to 1000 also but it is not working for me.

Comment: i have extended the time to 1000 also but it is not working for me.
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 1000
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 10